# where to get the keycode for keyboard hook in c#

Tags: c#, winapi

I am using the below code to disable the keyboard combination hooks.
I got this code while i surfed the net.
I want to know the list of keycodes for the keyboard keys. [lParam.vkCode == ???]
Please provide me the link for that, Thanks..

```
namespace BlockShortcuts

{

public class DisableKeys

{

private delegate int LowLevelKeyboardProcDelegate(int nCode, int wParam, ref KBDLLHOOKSTRUCT lParam);

[DllImport("user32.dll", EntryPoint = "SetWindowsHookExA", CharSet = CharSet.Ansi)]

private static extern int SetWindowsHookEx(int idHook, LowLevelKeyboardProcDelegate lpfn, int hMod, int dwThreadId);

[DllImport("user32.dll")]
private static extern int UnhookWindowsHookEx(int hHook);

[DllImport("user32.dll", EntryPoint = "CallNextHookEx", CharSet = CharSet.Ansi)]

private static extern int CallNextHookEx(int hHook, int nCode, int wParam, ref KBDLLHOOKSTRUCT lParam);

const int WH_KEYBOARD_LL = 13;

private int intLLKey;

private struct KBDLLHOOKSTRUCT
{
    public int vkCode;
    int scanCode;
    public int flags;
    int time;
    int dwExtraInfo;
}
private int LowLevelKeyboardProc(int nCode, int wParam, ref KBDLLHOOKSTRUCT lParam)
{
    bool blnEat = false; switch (wParam)
    {
        case 256:
        case 257:
        case 260:
        case 261:
            //Alt+Tab, Alt+Esc, Ctrl+Esc, Windows Key                           
            if (((lParam.vkCode == 9) && (lParam.flags == 32)) ||
                ((lParam.vkCode == 27) && (lParam.flags == 32)) ||
                ((lParam.vkCode == 27) && (lParam.flags == 0)) ||
                ((lParam.vkCode == 91) && (lParam.flags == 1)) ||
                ((lParam.vkCode == 92) && (lParam.flags == 1)) ||
                ((true) && (lParam.flags == 32)))
            {
                blnEat = true;
            }
            break;
    } if (blnEat) return 1; else return CallNextHookEx(0, nCode, wParam, ref lParam);
}
public void DisableKeyboardHook()
{
    intLLKey = SetWindowsHookEx(WH_KEYBOARD_LL, new LowLevelKeyboardProcDelegate(LowLevelKeyboardProc), System.Runtime.InteropServices.Marshal.GetHINSTANCE(System.Reflection.Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().GetModules()[0]).ToInt32(), 0);
}
private void ReleaseKeyboardHook()
{
    intLLKey = UnhookWindowsHookEx(intLLKey);
}
#endregion  
}

}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[Pinvoke.net](http://pinvoke.net/default.aspx/Enums/VirtualKeys.html) has them copy-paste ready.

Answer (score 6):

Start by looking at the definition of the callback [LowLevelKeyboardProc](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms644985(VS.85).aspx).
Then examine the definition of the struct that is your [lparam](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms644967(VS.85).aspx).
From there you can see that vkcode is a virtual key code. There is [a list of those on MSDN as well](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd375731(VS.85).aspx).

**EDIT:** As per comment, updated link to point to Windows Keyboard Input section of MSDN rather than the Windows CE Keyboard Input section of MSDN.

Comment: I would recommend going for this list: http://msdn.microsoft.com/de-de/ms645540%28en-us,VS.85%29.aspx
The other is for Windows CE ;)