# What are the virtualkey codes for following shortcut combinations in C#?

Tags: c#

I need to disable the following keyboard shortcuts like,

```
alt + tab

alt + esc 

ctrl + esc

windows key [this is not combination]
```

for which I need to provide the keycodes in my condition to make it disable.

I tried the following link: [MSDN Keycodes](http://msdn.microsoft.com/de-de/ms645540%28en-us,VS.85%29.aspx)

And did my condition like below:

```
if (((lParam.vkCode == 12) && (lParam.flags == 9)) ||    // alt + tab

((lParam.vkCode == 12) && (lParam.flags == 1)) ||        // alt + esc

 ((lParam.vkCode == 11) && (lParam.flags == 1)) ||       // ctr + esc

 ((lParam.vkCode == 5) && (lParam.flags == 0)) ||         // windows key
```

But it doesn't seem to work. Where am I going wrong?

If anyone needs to see my whole code to make the shortcuts disabled, see [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1198161/where-to-get-the-keycode-for-keyboard-hook-in-c) I posted before.

Comment: Grammar police checking in, somebody please change it to "What are the VirtualKey codes for the following shortcut combos in C#". On a helpful note, are you sure it doesn't use some sort of modifier value instead of just checking for the keypress?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your application will not receive virtual key events when these key combinations are pressed. They are handled specially by the operating system.

If you want to try to prevent users from trivially switching to other apps, then you could investigate creating your own desktop (CreateDesktop API), switching to that desktop (SwitchDesktop API), and then running your application code. I think that there will still be many ways a user could get around this but many users won't find them on their own.

I have not tried this myself, so YMMV.

Comment: @binarycoder,  if u see the code in
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1198161/where-to-get-the-keycode-for-keyboard-hook-in-c

This code is disabling the shorcut combos perfectly, but the keycodes dosent match with the keycodes provided by MSDN in 
http://msdn.microsoft.com/de-de/ms645540(en-us,VS.85).aspx

confused.....